# How to get rid of double decimal place

Tags: android

I'm trying to get rid of some of the decimal places in a double,I'v done it successfully on other part's of the app but i cant figure it out here. The double is coming in in a extra and i'm setting it to an edit text

```
double dryFree = sender.getExtras().getDouble("ResultFree");
  else if (getIntent().hasExtra("ResultFree")) {
        answer.setText( dryFree + "");
```

This is what i'v tried but app crashes

```
 else if (getIntent().hasExtra("ResultFree")) {
        answer.setText(String.format("%.2f", dryFree + ""));
```

Activity where number is coming from, I tried using string.format here to but getting errors, I know i'm using it wrong

```
total = (int) (a * b * c) / 0.424753;
```

Comment: in your String.format try taking out the extra `+ ""` so just `String.format("%.2f", dryFree)` ?

Comment: Thanks lads, working now